# Jquery Css change when div hit the top of the page

Tags: jquery, scroll

Good morning to everybody!

Today I'm in a trouble with this code...I want that the element ".cubo" moves when the "#team" section is in the viewport.

I tried with this code :

```
var team = $('#team').offset().top;

$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= team) {
            $('.cubo').css({top:"10%", left: "30%"});
        } else {
            $('.cubo').css({top: "0", left:"0"});
        }
    });
```

It works fine if I refresh the page when "#team" is already in the viewport...but if I scroll by the "#home" it doesn't works... why!??!

Please, can you tell me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the offset for the #team only when the page loads, then you are doing everything else when the page scrolls.

Try moving the offset var into your function so that it recalculates the offset on scroll.

```
$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
    var team = $('#team').offset().top;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= team) {
        $('.cubo').css({top:"10%", left: "30%"});
    } else {
        $('.cubo').css({top: "0", left:"0"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, too!

I think your javascript works, see the following snippet. Could you please post a snippet mocking your HTML and CSS? I think it has to do with that!

```js
var team = $('#team').offset().top;

$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= team) {
            $('.cubo').css({top:"10%", left: "30%"});
        } else {
            $('.cubo').css({top: "0", left:"0"});
        }
    });
```

```css
#container {
  height: 1000px;
}
.cubo {
  position: fixed;
}
#team {
  position: absolute;
  top:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
 <div class="cubo">
    CUBO
  </div>
  <div id="team">
    TEAM
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Johannes for your reply!